# How to retrieve a dynamic list of Components from a <tbody />?

Tags: angular

I'm creating a component that allow users to add/remove transaction lines from a grid. I have a `TranactionGridComponent` and `TransactionLineComponent`, and `TransactionGridComponent` is a parent component that can have  1-to-many `TransactionLineComponent`. I'm creating these `TransactionLineComponent`s dynamically when a user clicks "Add Line" and putting them into a `<table/>`. I have to number each line, and I will have to renumber these lines if any of the them are deleted by the user.

**How can I query `<table>`'s children components that are of type `TransactionLineComponent`?**

Answer (score 0):

Why would you need to query?

An array of data should be kept inside `TranactionGridComponent` or corresponding service.

While adding/deleting you only change this array, and the components would be added/removed automatically.

You can number the lines by using index in `ngFor`

```
<app-transaction-line *ngFor="#item of data; #i=index" [number]="i + 1">
```

Comment: `Why would you need to query?`
Because I don't want to create and maintain an array of references of `TransactionLineComponent` in `TransactionGirdComponent` that accurately reflects what's in the view. If the lines get reordered/deleted, I would have to write code to update the array accordingly which is an annoying pain.

Comment: I assume you came from `jquery` background? In `Angular` we do not create DOM elements directly upon data insert, we map models to views so that when we update a model, its representation in the view automatically reflects that.